# How to restrict which side of the form is sizable?

Tags: winforms, visual-c++

How do I make only the bottom of my vc++ windows form sizable and the rest of the sides (left, right, and top) not sizable?

I want the default arrow cursor to be displayed when moving around the 3 sides of my form (top side, left side, and right side) and the size NS arrow to be displayed and functional on the bottom of my form.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This requires falling back to handling the Windows notification directly, it isn't wrapped by the Form class.  You'll need to override the WndProc() method and customize the handling of WM_NCHITTEST.  Modify your stdafx.h file and add `#include <windows.h>` then add this code to your form:

```
protected:
    virtual void WndProc(Message% m) override {
        __super::WndProc(m);
        if (m.Msg == WM_NCHITTEST) {
            switch ((int)m.Result) {
                case HTLEFT: case HTRIGHT: case HTTOP: 
                case HTTOPLEFT: case HTTOPRIGHT:
                case HTBOTTOMLEFT: case HTBOTTOMRIGHT:
                    m.Result = (IntPtr)HTCLIENT;
            }
        }
    }
```